# informations about a matrix math structure

Tags: matrices

Suppose **S**={1,...,n}; we consider all the matrices **M(nxn)** where all the items **m_ij** are subsets of **S**. The operation on these matrices is **switch(a,b)** that change every occurrence of a with b and of b with a in every subset **m_ij**. Furthermore column a is switched with column b and the same for the rows a and b. My question: is there already a studied math object like this and what results have been reached? Thx

Comment: You mean all $m_{i,j}$ are **elements of** $S$ ?

Comment: No, are subsets of S like {},{1},{1,3},{1,2,...,n} etc

Comment: A framework would be endow the set $2^S$ of all subsets of $S$ a structure of a ring with additive law $\oplus$ and multiplicative law $\cap$. Matrices over a ring are studied objects...

Comment: ...But the framework I just gave has apparently nothing to do with the $a \leftrightarrow b$ exchanges you mention...  So the answer to your question is : it is doubtful that hundred of people around the world have worked on the subject, but... who knows ?

Comment: This kind of objects derive from graph representation and the switch came up when you invert the numerical name of two nodes

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much structure here. It's basically just a relabeling and a sort.